# How to add an extra form action on the user login page?

Tags: 7, users

I would like to add a link to the user registration page on the user login page. As I want the link to be placed right next to the **Login** button, I thought that adding an extra form action would be the easiest way to do this.

Should I add/edit some template or is there a hook for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) in order to modify the specific form.
You can add the action or the link there.
The link can be added using the #prefix,#suffix attributes of either the form or of a specific element.

Prefix example:

```
$form['#prefix'] = l(t('Link text'), 'my link');
```

Action example:

```
$form['actions']['add'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Add'),
  '#submit' => array('_my_callback_function'),
);
```

Comment: I don't think that he really need the custom submit handler if this is just a regular link (anchor). And you should use l function for the link.

Comment: The issue here is not providing the link itself. I believe that the answer is fully answering the question set.

Comment: Thanks, `$form['actions']['#suffix']` was exactly what I needed!